# Custom commands for Google Assistant SDK

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I've got a raspberry pi running the Google Assistant SDK, and it's working amazingly so far. I'm just wondering how I could make custom commands for the assistant, that would then trigger bash commands on the pi.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your own functions, call external commands, etc. using the pattern in `assistant_library_with_local_commands_demo.py` from the aiyprojects-raspbian project on GitHub. [Here is a commit](https://github.com/RichardBronosky/aiyprojects-raspbian/commit/c766449c129f2da2758d2d0918ae079f8f61158d) where I add my own custom local commands to Google Assistant.

You do have to jump through the hoops to use the Cloud Speech API, but it's still using the Google Assistant. You don't have to use "actions on Google" stuff described by @Ayoub above.

**Note:** If you fail to include the `assistant.stop_conversation()` as I first did,
you get a weird response with 2 voices talking to you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know what you are looking for is more complicated than that.
the assistant does not have direct access to its environment where it's installed.

So if it's on your phone you cannot just run something on the phone directly.

what you're looking for is to create an action on google:

- https://console.actions.google.com

the action on google that you will create will be triggered with your command on the assistant then it will it self trigger a webhook (function running in the cloud) hosted possibly in your pi (if you have a web server that you can access publicly) and then from there you can run whatever script you are talking about.
i have done that using my:

- google home ==> actions on google ==> api.ai ==> raspberrypi ==> run action

feel free to ask if you have any thing unclear.

Comment: I've heard of the webhooks approach, but I have no idea how to get that to work. Is there any tutorial I could follow, maybe? Thanks for responding, by the way.

Comment: yes, but first let me give you a quick explanation on how it work: 
you create a google action on console.actions.google.com 
Once done you need something for NLP (natural language processing) which in my case is API.ai and it's a google product.
then from there API.ai you have a section called fulfillment where you specify a url for a backend (webhook) that will make some computation for you and comeback with an anwser that will be sent to your google assistant device to host your fulfilment locally search for ngrok
the video that i used:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y26vvxCb3zE

Comment: I cannot accept that it is this complicated. They have this demo included in the code. I just haven't managed to get it to work. https://github.com/google/aiyprojects-raspbian/blob/aiyprojects/src/assistant_library_with_local_commands_demo.py#L68-L73

Comment: Give my answer a shot and tell me if it can be used to do what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48047201/117471